# Conditional Probability Problem $P(a < b < c)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

From the set from {$1, ..., N$} according to the selection scheme without return, the numbers $a,  b, c$ are selected. Find the probability that $P (a < b < c) = \text{?}$

My solution is $$P(a < b < c) =\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{l=1}^m \frac{1}{N}\frac{N-k}{N-1}\frac{N-l}{N-2}$$
where $k$ and $l$ is the numbers that were selected the first time and the second time.

The questions: is this result correct? You can show solutions from the formal side?

Comment: Summing over all possible outcomes is one way to solve this, but I think it's probably easier to make some kind of a "by symmetry" argument. According to my intuition, all orderings are equally likely, so the probability is 1/6.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(a < b < c) + P(a < c < b) + P(c < b < a) +P(b<c<a) + P(b<a<c) + P(c<a<b) = 1$$

and each of those terms has equal probability. So each has probability 1/6.